# Altair: Converting Y-Axis to % Format in Global Configuration (vs Local Config)

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

I need my Y-axis labels to be in the '%' format. I know how to do this with local configuration:

```
line1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(
).encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', title="Some Title", axis=alt.Axis(format='%')), 
)

line1
```

In the above example, the "axis=alt.Axis(format='%')" argument converts the axis to % instead of decimal.

What I need to know, however, is how to do this for the global configuration. For instance:

```
line1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(
).encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y=alt.Y('value:Q'), 
)

line1.properties(
        width=800, 
        height=500, 
    ).configure_axisY(
        labelFontSize=15,
        titleFontSize=15, 
    )
```

Is there an attribute for .configure_axisY() that I can use to do this? I am [glancing through all the options](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.configure_axisY) and nothing seems obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chart.configure(numberFormat='%')`. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', freq='D', periods=7),
    'value': np.linspace(0, 1, 7),
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', title="Some Title"), 
).configure(
    numberFormat='%'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I never would've guessed that one. Thanks, Jake!

Answer (score 0):

you can specify argument `axis=alt.Axis(format='%')` to y.

ref: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#adjusting-axis-labels